# Python - Selenium - webscrape xmlns table

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<html xmlns="hyyp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>_</head>
    <body>
        <form name="Main Form" method="post" action="HTMLReport.aspx?ReportName=...">
            <div id="Whole">
                <div id="ReportHolder">
                    <table xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemeas-microsoft-com:xslt" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>_</td>
                                <td>LIVE</td>
                                and the data I need is here between <td> </td>
```

Now my code so far is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOps=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOps._binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
chromeOps._arguments = ["--enable-internal-flash"]

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe", port=4445, chrome_options=chromeOps)
time.sleep(3)

browser.get('website')
elem=browser.find_element_by_id('MainForm')
el=elem.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]')
```

the last two lines of code are just really me testing how path I can go before xpath breaksdown.  Trying to xpath to any content beyond this point gives a noSuchElementException.

Can anyone explain to me how I draw data from within the table please?

My currently thinking is that perhaps I have to pass "something" into an xml tree api and access it through that.  Although I don't know how I would capture it.

If anyone can give me that next step it would be greatly appreciated, feeling a bit like I'm holding a candle in a dark room at the moment.

Comment: To clarify, if you use an xpath such as: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ReportHolder']/table/tbody/tr")` you're receiving an exception?

Comment: Yes that is correct.
In my example: 
    el=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table/tbody/tr')
produces a noSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.  It's a timing issue.

Solution:  Place a time.sleep(5) before the xpath request.

```
browser.get('http://www.mmgt.co.uk/HTMLReport.aspx?ReportName=Fleet%20Day%20Summary%20Report&ReportType=7&CategoryID=4923&Startdate='+strDate+'&email=false')
time.sleep(5)
ex=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table/tbody/tr/td')
```

xpath is requesting a reference to dynamic content.

The table is dynamic content and takes longer to load that content then it does for the python program to reach line:

```
ex=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ReportHolder"]/table/tbody/tr')
```

from its previous line of:

```
browser.get('http://www.mmgt.co.uk/HTMLReport.aspx?ReportName=Fleet%20Day%20Summary%20Report&ReportType=7&CategoryID=4923&Startdate='+strDate+'&email=false')
```

Comment: Rather than using the `time.sleep()` try using the inbuilt `WebdriverWait` class and the supporting `ExpectedConditions`. For example, `WebdriverWait(self.druver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath here"))`